# how to map list indices to dataframe index and flag where it matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have following list

```
  [4,5,6]
```

I have following dataframe

```
  index    quantity
  0        12
  1        45
  2        56
  3        55
  4        65
  5        43
  6        23
  7        34
```

I want to flag list indices in a new column in dataframe where it matches with dataframe index.

```
 index    quantity    flag
  0        12         0
  1        45         0
  2        56         0
  3        55         0
  4        65         1
  5        43         1
  6        23         1 
  7        34         0
```

How do I do it in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) for boolean mask and cast it to integer - `True/False`s to `1/0`s:

```
L = [4,5,6]
df['flag'] = df.index.isin(L).astype(int)
print (df)
       quantity  flag
index                
0            12     0
1            45     0
2            56     0
3            55     0
4            65     1
5            43     1
6            23     1
7            34     0
```